# Visual Studio puts the controller / tool somewhere other place on the Form than where I placed it

Tags: winforms, ide, visual-studio-2019

I develop a WinForm app in Visual Studio 2019, but there is an annoying problem:

When I place a controller / tool on my Form and released the mouse button, VS puts it somwehere other place.

1. I want it here:

[image]

2. VS puts it here (after release the mouse button):

[image]

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this happens, but you can use keyboard keys after adding tool from toolbox to change its location

Comment: Thank You for the quick answer! This is useful.